# Evaluate and Predict functions in Keras are not giving the same statistics

Tags: keras

I have a very simple DNN with a given data set. However, the standard deviation of error I got from "evaluate" and "predict" are different. The mean error seems OK but the stdev from predict is always larger than the stdev from evaluate. Why do these differences happen and how can I fix it?

[Raw data is here for download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vB06ZDh3dNFR1f931Xl9xajVmHSJgm11/view?usp=sharing)

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
import keras.backend as K
from keras import optimizers
import pickle
import numpy as np

with open('.\\dump','rb') as f:
    xTr = pickle.load(f)
    yTr = pickle.load(f)
    muX = pickle.load(f)
    stdX = pickle.load(f)
    muY = pickle.load(f)
    stdY = pickle.load(f)

def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = y_true*stdY + muY
    y_pred = y_pred*stdY + muY
    return K.mean(y_pred - y_true)

def std_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = y_true*stdY + muY
    y_pred = y_pred*stdY + muY
    return K.std(y_pred - y_true)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
adam = optimizers.adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=adam,loss='mse', metrics=[mean_pred, std_pred])
model.fit(xTr, yTr.reshape(-1,1), epochs = 5, batch_size = 128, verbose=0, shuffle=True)

score = model.evaluate(xTr, yTr.reshape(-1,1), verbose=0)
pred = model.predict(xTr, verbose=0)

print(score) #mse, mean, stdev of error

errArr = []
for i,y in enumerate(yTr):
    errArr.append((pred[i][0] - y)*stdY)
e = np.asarray(errArr)
print(e.mean(), e.std()) #mean, stdev of error
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the reason... By default, evaluate is not using all samples even if batch_size is set to none. After set batch_size = 1000 (number of samples in my data set), I got the same mean and standard deviation of error